# Memory leak while using stringwithformat

Tags: objective-c

i found a memory leaks in the add target line of following code and i am releasing ui button properly i dont no why this is happening.

```
UIButton *btnProjectName = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 170, 40)];
btnProjectName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
btnProjectName.tag=obj.tagNo;
[btnProjectName addTarget:self action:@selector(projectName_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

/* ... */

[btnproject release];
```

Comment: You've found the memory leak? So what's the question?

Comment: What type of object is leaking? How did you discover the leak?

Comment: @Geoffroy, Nowhere he is using `stringWithFormat`.. May I know why have you changed the title to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happens where you write `/* ... */`. There may be a return statement hidden in there. In which case it will cause a leak. This will deal with this scenario.

```
UIButton *btnProjectName = [[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 170, 40)] autorelease];
```

Also remove the `[btnProjectName release];` near the bottom.

---

If it's a new Xcode project then consider using [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).